# How to make automated test scripts in protractor wait, until the page is loaded fully

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protractor, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

No, but really! I know this generic question has been asked thousands of times, but there is something more specific that looks feasible to me and thus I want to know how to achieve it

### The problem

I'm testing an angular app with [protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api). Inside the app I want to verify that when I click a link I'm being redirected to the right page (non-angular). The problem is that until I reach the page I'm verifying, the url changes 3 times or so (there are multiple redirections happening), so I can't make a waiting function wait until the page is loaded completely

### What I tried/what won't work for me

1. I'm against `browser.sleep()` for more than 1000 ms!
2. `browser.waitForAngular()` as this is not an angular page
3. `ExpectedConditions.urlIs()` the url is the variable I'm asserting
4. `ExpectedConditions.presenseOf()` the page maybe changing so I can't rely on elements inside
5. `browser.executeScript("return window.document.readyState")` returns `compete` immediately, though the page is still loading (I was certain this is what I need, but that didn't work either)
6. I tried even adding a functions that waits for `innerHtml` of the whole page not change for at least 3 sec, but it fails because at times there is a pause of more than 3 sec between redirects are happening. Everything above 3 sec isn't a reasonable timeout

### The question

What I noticed is when the browser is loading the page, `Reload this page` button changes its state to `Stop loading this page` (X icon) until I'm redirected to the final page (screenshots below). So the question is **is there a way to make protractor point to the same condition that chrome uses to choose which icon is displayed?**

[image]

vs

[image]

And if not exactly the same, but how do I make protractor hang until the page is **fully** loaded

### Important to consider

Obviously there are a lot of dirty solutions that I can do like explicit waits. But I'm coming back to this question every once in a while, so I'm not interested in these dirty solutions that work 70% of the time for a specific cause

P.S. I figured that the button changes the icon on `document.load()` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event). But I can't figure out what should I write in the console in order for that script to log a message when I refresh they page

Comment: This is a really good question. I had the same question when I had like 3 redirects during the login flow. However wait for  `presenceOf` + disabling waitForAngular worked in my case. It's a shot shot in the dark, but what about checking the local storage for presence of some particular data?

Comment: as an option, yes, might work. But you're still expecting to see something in particular (i.e. you know ahead of time what you'll see), whereas I'm looking for a universal way to wait until the browser itself stops loading and says the page is ready. And more importantly based on my research it's feasible @YuriyGerasimovich

Comment: For DOM you can try DOMContentLoaded event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event). However this does not  guarantee that all api calls has finished, BUT if the app is designed in the proper way DOM should not be "finished" until all calls are done (page should use spinners/loaders etc.)

Comment: Too late to edit the previous comment, but  `readyState` can be handy as well (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) @Sergey Pleshakov

Comment: Thank you @YuriyGerasimovich but as you see I tried that already and for some reasons I get `"complete"` readyState immediately when pages are still loading. So yeah, it should be working, but it doesn't for some reason... I also found out that `document.load()` is more suitable for this need. But I can't think of a way to crack it

Comment: it will try this as well when I will have time and will share results here

Answer (score 0):

I have the following snippet for just the problem, I wait for an element to be displayed:

```
ElementFinder.prototype.secureIsDisplayed = function () {
return browser
.wait(EC.visibilityOf(this), actionTimeout)
.then(() => this.isDisplayed())
.catch(err => {
    throw new Error(`Expected ElementFinder ${this.locator()} to be displayed. ${err.toString()}`);
});
};
```

where `actionTimeout` is a const int and `EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions` you will need to import the file and call it like so:

```
import './asd.ts'
element(by.css('.myClass')). secureIsDisplayed()
```

I if you can find the last element that loads, or just get an element of a redirect it can do wonders.
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution Peter, but this would mean I need to know what I'm waiting for, whereas I'm looking for a way to wait until the browser says the page is ready (regardless of the content)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
browser.executeScript("return window.jQuery.active").equals(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
await browser.wait(async () =>
        await browser.driver.executeScript('return document.readyState;') === 'loading', 2000)
        .then(() => true, () => true);
await browser.wait(async () =>
        await browser.driver.executeScript('return document.readyState;') === 'complete', 5000)
```

Comment: Yes it's #5 in my question. Idk why it's not working, though it should. I'll try your code as well, since it's slightly different. Thank you