# Protractor for Angular : Wait for HTTP requests to finish before continuing the script

Tags: angular, testing, request, protractor

When I run my E2E testing script using protractor, the thing I do is that I do many `browser.sleep(xxxx)` to wait a moment for all HTTP requests (GET, POST, PUT,...) to end, because otherwise if I don't do this protractor does not wait and I can't do and test what I want to test in my angular application.

So is there a way to make sure that the script will not continue until all HTTP requests are no longer in status pending ?

My config file :

```
allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
```

Comment: Is there anything that happens *within the UI* that tells you that the requests have completed? Then you can base your tests on user-observable behaviour.

Comment: In some pages yes, and in some other pages no, and I don't really want to check by verifying DOM elements to check if API calls are not done. For me it's not the best thing to do. I though that protractor "understand" the way angular works. I once read that protractor wait until requests are done, but it seems like it is not the case.

Comment: AFAIK no you cant wait for API calls to complete from protractor.But when all main requests are done browser fires `load` event to signal that the page is loaded.In networks tab grapth it's represented by red vertical line as appose to blue line that represents `DOMContentLoaded` event.When `load` event is fired the 'stop loading' button icon changes to 'refresh page` So currently I'm looking for a way to connect those

Comment: In my understanding this is what you need. Because you don't want to wait for ALL requests, because they can keep coming infinitely. Join the discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115462/how-to-make-automated-test-scripts-in-protractor-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded. I plan to involve connections from google chrome team soon

Comment: Do you have a solution for me to do that ? To check and wait until the page is not loaded yet and is still loading ?